# How to save 2 models in one transaction using ActiveModel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-model-serializers

I have a little class that works with 4 models. I'd like to do things the "right" way. Basically, I want to create 2 `Address` models, 1 `Shipment` (w/ 2 address_ids, and `1 Parcel` that belongs to `Shipment`.

At this point, I'm confused. I need to get past this and onto the next big milestone. Does this look promising, or do you recommends saving 2 records in the controller, then use an after_create, or something similar? Thank you.

```
class Quote
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor address_to: {
                  :name, :company, :street1, :street2, :street3, :city, :state, 
                  :zip, :country, :phone, :email},
                address_from: {
                  :name, :company, :street1, :street2, :street3, :city, :state, 
                  :zip, :country, :phone, :email
                }
  def save
    return false if invalid?

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      user.addresses.create!([{address_from, address_to}]) # how to do this?

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Model association through the tags `:belongs_to` and `:has_many`,
you could use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :another_child_model` for example. It will automatically create or define this association if you permit those params on the controller.

[Rails guide for nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Pay attention on permitting those attributes on the controller.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
   ...
   def your_params
      params.require(:entity).permit(:etc, :etc, child_model_attributes: [:id, :name, :etc, :etc])
   end
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use callbacks on models. Hard to test models, unpredictable behavior.
2. U can use accept_nested_attributes.
3. If u will have a custom logic with that, u can use Service Objects pattern and put all logic there.
   But if u want do it like u do then try to use `user.addresses.create!([address_from, address_to])`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Rails 6` or a higher version - there is a method called `insert_all` to insert multiple records to the database in one `INSERT` statement.

Check it out on apidock: [insert_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/insert_all)

Example:

```
Book.insert_all([
  { id: 1, title: "Rework", author: "David" },
  { id: 1, title: "Eloquent Ruby", author: "Russ" }
])
```

(example from the docs)